# Accessing AWS athena service from databricks using athena JDBC Driver (Simba jdbc jar)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena, databricks

I created a java application to connect to athena using AthenaJDBC jar (v4.2) and running that jar from a databricks notebook for executing queries. It works fine but i need to pass the IAM user credentials (Access key and Secret Key) for making the connection to athena. 
I don't want to pass user credentials in java code. Instead want to use the databricks IAM role to access aws athena service. Is there a way to do that ?
I am new to athena, please help me connect athena using IAM role of databricks.